# AWS Terraform aws_db_instance & aws_rds_cluster 's address and endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I'm studying AWS with Terraform. The question is => aws_db_instance and aws_rds_cluster, if I output the address and endpoint through outputs respectively, what type of value will I get? (Like ~.com:3306. But I can't find information when I search which one is which.)

Questions:

```
aws_db_instance.example.address
aws_db_instance.example.endpoint
aws_rds_cluster.example.address
aws_rds_cluster.example.endpoint
```

What I've tried: I've seen the official document, but it's only written in sentences, so I don't know the actual format. I can't find out know which one is `~.com:3306` format and which is `~.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#address):

> `address` - The hostname of the RDS instance.

"hostname" means that this is only the DNS hostname, i.e. excluding the port.

> `endpoint` - The connection endpoint in `address:port` format.

This specifies the format as being `address:port`